# Apec Class Issue when parsing a text string back to a record

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, parsing

I have a LWC that essentially collects data in a table format.

I am then using an apex action (apex class) to parse the text string output of the LWC back to a record - see the code below:

```
public without sharing class PointofConnSingle {
    //input details that comes to apex from flow
    public class FlowInputs{
    
        @InvocableVariable
        public string applicationIdString;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public string propertyChildStringArray;
        
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Point Of Connection Saving Single Apex')
    public static List<String> saveMainsData(List<FlowInputs> request){

        List<string> applicationIdList = new List <string>();
        List<string> propertyChildStringArrayList = new List<string>();
        List<string> resultResponse = new list<string>();
        List<property__c> newPropertyToInsertList = new List<property__c>();

        for(FlowInputs requestItem : request){           
            applicationIdList.add(requestItem.applicationIdString);
            propertyChildStringArrayList.add(requestItem.propertyChildStringArray);
        }

        try{

            Id applicationId = Id.valueOf(applicationIdList[0]);        
            //main property array- processing Json
            List<PropertyJsonClass> mainPropList = PropertyJsonClass.parse(propertyChildStringArrayList[0]);
 
            //inserting property frist
            for(PropertyJsonClass resultPropItem: mainPropList) {                                  
                property__c newProperty = new property__c();
                newProperty.Application__c = applicationId;
                newProperty.Type_of_Property_POC__c = resultPropItem.propertyType;
                newProperty.Name = resultPropItem.propertyType;
                newProperty.Units__c = filterResponse(resultPropItem.unit);
                newProperty.Imp_Areas_M__c = filterResponse(resultPropItem.impAreas);
                newProperty.Name = resultPropItem.propertyType;
                newPropertyToInsertList.add(newProperty);            
            } 
 
            if(!newPropertyToInsertList.isEmpty()){
                system.debug('adding property records');
                insert newPropertyToInsertList;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            resultResponse.add('INSERT Failed' + e);
        }

        resultResponse.add('OK');
        return resultResponse;
   
    }
    
       private static integer filterResponse(String dataToFilter){
        if(dataToFilter!='' && dataToFilter!=null){
            return integer.valueOf(dataToFilter);
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }      
}
```

This works if the value put into the Units__c or Imp_Areas_M__c field is an integer but fails if a decimal is entered.

The data is entered via a LWC that outputs a text string that this code then parses into the fields

any ideas?

I assumed the Private static class at the bottom converts the value to a integer - but obviously not

Error Message is - The number of results does not match the number of interviews that were executed in a single bulk execution request.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because if an exception is thrown, the `catch` statement adds `'INSERT Failed'`, but after catching you add an `'OK'` message. Please move the `'OK'` statement addition above before the `catch` block.

Comment: Thanks i will try this

Comment: Sorry to be a pain i am not a coder - how would it be written - i have tried cutting a pasting but i am getting an error compliting

Comment: ```... insert newPropertyToInsertList; }
/* add here */resultResponse.add('OK'); /* add here end */
}catch(Exception e){
resultResponse.add('INSERT Failed' + e);
} /* remove  resultResponse.add('OK') from there*/
return resultResponse;
}
...
```

Comment: @Matt here you go

Comment: Thank you @Jack